# How do I remove the last line and 1st and last quotation marks from the clipboard using apple script?

Tags: applescript, clipboard, automator

I'm a newbie and I'm trying to use applescript to able to format text that I copied onto a clipboard then use workflows in automator to make copy pasting quicker.

Whenever I copy from iBooks and paste to a notetaking app, it comes with citations which makes it very tedious to remove when you're trying to compile the notes and summarize. The segment gets put into quotation marks then theres a change in line then the last line Excerpt from...

What I want is remove that last line then remove the 1st and last quotation marks above it. Could someone please tell me the syntax for that? I'm going mad trying to understand coding and workflows :( I'm trying to use automator for that.

Comment: Paste a sample of the original text that's on the clipboard to help illustrate. But, what you're really asking is how to "find and replace" using AppleScript, and it's hard to believe you can't search for that.

Comment: You are practically asking for a solution to your specific requirement, I wouldn't recommend doing that in this forum. Though you could try to post a sample as mentioned by @jweaks, not that it's not easy to do, and perhaps somebody with spare time would help you out given how straightforward your requirement is.